# Access denied error when building project in Xcode after fresh SVN checkout

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, svn

I am seeing 2 strange access denied errors which I cant solve.  This error occurs when a colleague checks out the project in SVN and it tries to find a file in my downloads folder - there is nothing in my download folder though:

```
 ProcessPCH /var/folders/f0/f01B78egHdyWY62v5MABJk+++TM/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.502/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/SplitView_Prefix-allviomrzhantlbahmhixtzhknpl/SplitView_Prefix.pch.gch SplitView_Prefix.pch normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_2
    cd /SubVersion/SplitView/trunk/SplitView
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x objective-c-header -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -fvisibility=hidden -gdwarf-2 -mno-thumb -miphoneos-version-min=4.2 -iquote /SubVersion/SplitView/trunk/SplitView/build/SplitView.build/Debug-iphoneos/Renovatio.build/SplitView-generated-files.hmap -I/SubVersion/SplitView/trunk/SplitView/build/SplitView.build/Debug-iphoneos/Renovatio.build/SplitView-own-target-headers.hmap -I/SubVersion/SplitView/trunk/SplitView/build/SplitView.build/Debug-iphoneos/Renovatio.build/SplitView-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /SubVersion/SplitView/trunk/SplitView/build/SplitView.build/Debug-iphoneos/Renovatio.build/SplitView-project-headers.hmap -Wno-write-strings -F/SubVersion/SplitView/trunk/SplitView/build/Debug-iphoneos -F/SubVersion/SplitView/trunk/SplitView -F/Users/Username/Downloads -I/SubVersion/SplitView/trunk/SplitView/build/Debug-iphoneos/include -I/SubVersion/SplitView/trunk/SplitView/build/SplitView.build/Debug-iphoneos/Renovatio.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/SubVersion/SplitView/trunk/SplitView/build/SplitView.build/Debug-iphoneos/Renovatio.build/DerivedSources -fno-regmove -falign-loops=16 -fvisibility=default -c /SubVersion/SplitView/trunk/SplitView/SplitView_Prefix.pch -o /var/folders/f0/f01B78egHdyWY62v5MABJk+++TM/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.502/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/SplitView_Prefix-allviomrzhantlbahmhixtzhknpl/SplitView_Prefix.pch.gch

cc1objplus: error: /Users/MyUsername/Downloads: Permission denied

    ProcessPCH++ /var/folders/f0/f01B78egHdyWY62v5MABJk+++TM/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.502/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/SplitView_Prefix-fdhrznnmptbkzefjexcjfecmqxmq/SplitView_Prefix.pch.gch SplitView_Prefix.pch normal armv7 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_2
    cd /SubVersion/SplitView/trunk/SplitView
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x objective-c++-header -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -gdwarf-2 -mno-thumb -miphoneos-version-min=4.2 -iquote /SubVersion/SplitView/trunk/SplitView/build/SplitView.build/Debug-iphoneos/Renovatio.build/SplitView-generated-files.hmap -I/SubVersion/SplitView/trunk/SplitView/build/SplitView.build/Debug-iphoneos/Renovatio.build/SplitView-own-target-headers.hmap -I/SubVersion/SplitView/trunk/SplitView/build/SplitView.build/Debug-iphoneos/Renovatio.build/SplitView-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /SubVersion/SplitView/trunk/SplitView/build/SplitView.build/Debug-iphoneos/Renovatio.build/SplitView-project-headers.hmap -Wno-write-strings -F/SubVersion/SplitView/trunk/SplitView/build/Debug-iphoneos -F/SubVersion/SplitView/trunk/SplitView -F/Users/Username/Downloads -I/SubVersion/SplitView/trunk/SplitView/build/Debug-iphoneos/include -I/SubVersion/SplitView/trunk/SplitView/build/SplitView.build/Debug-iphoneos/Renovatio.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/SubVersion/SplitView/trunk/SplitView/build/SplitView.build/Debug-iphoneos/Renovatio.build/DerivedSources -c /SubVersion/SplitView/trunk/SplitView/SplitView_Prefix.pch -o /var/folders/f0/f01B78egHdyWY62v5MABJk+++TM/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.502/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/SplitView_Prefix-fdhrznnmptbkzefjexcjfecmqxmq/SplitView_Prefix.pch.gch

    cc1objplus: error: /Users/MyUsername/Downloads: Permission denied
```

Comment: @Paul R - I deliberately removed my username before posting this in StackOverflow - so it is looking for something in my user folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s a

```
 -F/Users/Username/Downloads
```

in the GCC invocation command. It looks like you’ve linked a framework that resides in your Downloads folder and that got committed to the Subversion repository. You need to agree on a standard location for that framework (maybe the Subversion repository itself) and use it instead of ~/Downloads.

Comment: Tks but how do I get rid of it or change it?  Nube

Comment: @TheLearner Remove the offending framework from Linked Frameworks in your project tree, move it to a standard location (either in your Subversion repository or a username-agnostic location), relink the framework by dragging it from the new location to the Linked Frameworks group in your project tree, and commit the changes. I think placing the framework in your Subversion repository under the project directory is the best solution.